# Apache rewrite in docker not working for PHP files

Tags: docker, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My docker container apache seems to be unable to rewrite requests for `.php` files. Interestingly enough, any other file type seems to work just fine.

For example with this simple `.htaccess` configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.txt$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ index.php [L]
```

Every request ending with `.php`,`.html`,`.txt` or `.xml` should be rewritten to `index.php`. However all request ending with `.php` are ignored and the requested file is shown, as if there was no configuration at all.

Dockerfile:

```
ARG APACHE_VERSION=""
FROM httpd:${APACHE_VERSION:+${APACHE_VERSION}-}alpine

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

# Copy apache vhost file to proxy php requests to php-fpm container
COPY project.apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

.env (configuration)

```
APACHE_VERSION=2.4
PROJECT_ROOT=./www
```

compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: './apache/'
      args:
        APACHE_VERSION: ${APACHE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
    container_name: apache
```

Apache config:

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not certainly sure if the issue lies within docker or apache so the question might need to be renamed.

Here is the full docker config that I am using if anyone wants to reproduce the issue inside their own docker: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D_a-9d_BfomzrAjSxGNo8M3nZ1s2imU9/view?usp=sharing

It has a .bat file for automatic setup so the only thing you need to run it is a working docker.

Comment: .htaccess is enabled and when I place the rules inside VirtualHost, I get the same result. Its just more convenient for me to use .htaccess

Comment: Well I put the rules inside the section and removed them from .htaccess and I got exactly the same result.

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to the whole config so anyone can replicate the problem

Comment: I was able to recreate setup using provided docker package. Your rules are also working fine. When I visited `http://localhost/abcd123.html` it showed content from `index.php` with message as `Index.php is being shown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this `ProxyPassMatch` line:

```sh
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
```

Which is proxying every `*.php` requests to port `9000` of the `php-fpm` container.

This directive runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and handles all `*.php` files, thus your rewrite rule in `.htaccess` to rewrite all `*.php` URIs is never invoked.

You can change this directive to proxy only `/index.php` and let all remaining `.php` requests to flow through to `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` like this.

```sh
ProxyPassMatch ^/(index\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
```

You can refactor your .htaccess like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule \.(php|html?|xml)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but is there no other way around this? What if I want to change the `.htaccess` file for another project? Or make more sophisticated changes? This sounds like a really non-universal solution. Can't I execute the php code in a different way? Or maybe make the proxy take place after the rewrites?

Comment: Proxy will happen before rewrite but you have to stop using php-fpm altogether